# Python "requests" not working / blocking in a thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, visual-studio, python-requests

I've tried the `requests` module in python 2.7 and liked it a lot, but when I tried to use it in a thread, it doesn't seem to work:

```
def doWork():
    try:
        print "before"
        requests.get('http://www.google.fr')
        print "after"
    except Exception as e:
        print "Error : "+ str(e)

# Working : I see "before" & "after"
doWork()

# Not working, i see "before" but never "after"
t = Thread(target=doWork)
t.start()
```

I it tried this way but it's the same:

```
class TestThread(Thread):
    def run(self):
        try:
            print "before"
            requests.get('http://www.google.fr')
            print "after"
        except Exception as e:
            print "Error : "+ str(e)

test_thread = TestThread()
test_thread.start() # I will see "before" but never "after"
test_thread.join()
```

I tried to wait few minutes (hours), but it is still not working; neither `after` nor an error is ever printed. I probably missed something but I can't see what.

I am using Requests 2.9.1; Python 2.7.11 (Anaconda 2.4.1 32bits)
and I'm on Windows 7.

Comment: Please provide `requests.__version__`, `sys.version` and which OS you're using

Comment: I edited my post with informations you asked.

Comment: are you running this in the shell or from a `.py` file

Comment: I added the `test_thread.join()` there so that people do not suggest it.

Comment: +Antti Haapala I'm using visual studio with the python tools developer, so i'm not sure. I'm gonna try by running directly the .py from cmd console.

Comment: Yeah, that is a good idea.

Comment: It's working for me.

Comment: The obvious solution is to join the thread, why is joining a thread a problem for you OP? btw when I run it from the shell it works as expected

Comment: join the thread is one of first things i tried but didn't worked. It's tried with run() and it's working. I tried to run it directly by cmd console, and it's working with start()... Well thanks for your help, i'm gonna use run for the moment.

Comment: @KDawG There is no need to call `join()` explicitly. Python process won't exit until all non-daemon threads are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i digged about this and found the problem (who is not from visual studio). I tried new project and had no issues.

I know that the "main" file of python is not compiled, so i did that :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import compiled_main
```

where "compiled_main" is the code i posted before for exemple. On this way, any threads who use "requests" will stay blocked, the request will never be executed and will never raise any exception. If i do join(), my code will wait a thread who will never be released.

*Using ".run()" worked, but it's not starting a thread, i checked and noticied that will just call the method as classic method, so it's not a solution.*

**Solution : Never start a thread directly in a file who will be imported**

Solution 1 : Create an init() method who contains all the code and call it in the main like this

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import compiled_main
    compiled_main.init()
```

Solution 2 : Execute your code directly in your main (the real one, not compiled)

*Thanks everyone for your help, you guided me to the solution (especially +Antti Haapala)*

Comment: 1- Don't confuse `.run()` and `.start()` methods. **Never call `.run()` manually.** 2- you can start a thread at the global level without `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard. It has no effect on requests. It shouldn't block the main thread either way